# Table not visible inside database

Tags: mysql

I have copied a table (arts2.frm) from another computer and pasted it in C>XAMPP>MySql>Data>admission2 of my computer so that I can work with the structure and data of arts2.frm. But I cannot see the table inside the database admission2.

I am using phpmyadmin 127.0.0.1 downloaded free from web. I am just a beginner in this field. Please excuse my ignorance and help me in this regard.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use the phpmyadmin interface for this? go to the table, click export, check view output as text, click go. copy the dump text, then go to the new db and run it as sql

Comment: `.frm` files store the definition of the table, not the data itself. The `.frm` files exist largely for administrative reasons. You should export your data and then import it instead of moving files around - especially as the binary format of MySQL's files can vary between versions - this applies to every DBMS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No tables found in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338222/no-tables-found-in-database)