# No tables found in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have copied a database from another computer and pasted it in C>XAMPP>MySql>Data   of my computer so that I can work with the tables of the database. But I cannot see the tables inside the database. Message shows 'No tables found in database'

I am using phpmyadmin 127.0.0.1 downloaded free from web. I am just a beginner in this field. Please excuse my ignorance and help me in this regard.

Comment: You can't just copy-paste MySQL database like in SQL Server. Please read this http://www.itworld.com/it-management/359857/3-ways-import-and-export-mysql-database

Comment: One does not simply copy and paste. One must use the export/import option provide.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your_db.sql file import the database and tables into MySql server using phpmyadmin. You can check [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/import-and-export-databases-using-phpmyadmin/)

Answer (score -1):

The approach guaranteed is to Export from the source computer and Import to the destination computer; that is guaranteed and will work perfectly. Try that!

Do this from your phpmyadmin